# JQuery function not returning JSON list - Play Framework, JPA

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, coffeescript, playframework-2.5

I'm realtively new to Play and am trying to walk through the exercise in the intro Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc).

I'm doing a couple of things differently. 1) I'm using a more recent version of Play (2.5 something). I'm also using JPA instead of eBean for my persistence layer and a local Postgres DB rather than the h2 In memory DB. That shouldn't affect my issue, though.

Basically, I have added a "/persons" GET endpoint that returns the people in my Person table in JSON format. I have confirmed this works and is returning valid JSON.

However, My JQuery doesn't seem to be reaching it. Based on the tutorial, I have written my query in Coffeescript and am now inspecting the Javascript that it's compiled to.

Here is the coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $.get "/persons", (persons) ->
    $.each persons, (index, person) ->
      $('#persons').append $("<li>").text person.name
```

Here is the translated javascript (located at http://localhost:8080/assets/js/index.js as expected):

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $.get("/persons", function(persons) {
      return $.each(persons, function(index, person) {
        return $('#persons').append($("<li>").text(person.name);
      });
    });
  });

}).call(this);

//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

This is my template:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    <script type='type/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("js/index.js")'></script>

    <ul id="persons"></ul>

    <form action="@routes.HomeController.addPerson()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <button>Add Person</button>
    </form>

}
```

The "Add Person" is working. I'm able to persist Persons and see them when I manually do a http://localhost:8080/persons in my browser.

Obviously my javascript skills aren't that strong, so any help with what might be going wrong or how I could further troubleshoot why the li's aren't being populated would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also just noticed the return $('#persons').append($("<li>").text(person.name); is missing one extra closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a missing closed parenthesis in the end.

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $.get("/persons", function(persons) {
      return $.each(persons, function(index, person) {
        return $('#persons').append($("<li>").text(person.name)); //here
      });
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8va4k4wu/2/

Comment: Thanks. I tried abandoning the coffescript (just javascript) and modifying it as you said, same behavior unfortunately. Not li's are adding to the ul

Comment: I started a jsfiddle and tried to do something similar.  Do all those functions and returns gain you something?  I tried to simplify it a bit, but am curious to know.  Let me know if this example works for you. https://jsfiddle.net/8va4k4wu/1

Comment: I also got it to work by adding the extra closing parenthesis.  See my comments on the question.  https://jsfiddle.net/8va4k4wu/2/  I simulated the $.get call with just some assumed json.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. After inserting some console.log lines in my javascript and realizing the function isn't actually getting hit, I realized there was a typo in my template script tag:

```
<script type='type/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("js/index.js")'></script>
```

script type should be 'text/javascript' instead of 'type/javascript'.

Modifying this lead to a console output of a 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined' which quickly led me to this issue and the proposed solution worked for me:

[Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (using play framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788728/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-using-play-framework)